# how to combine two figures into one in matlab?

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, figures

so I built two normal distributions.. I want to to combine both into a single image, with the two images overlapping partially to look something like this:
[two plots http://www.uark.edu/misc/lampinen/tutorials/image8BK.JPG](http://www.uark.edu/misc/lampinen/tutorials/image8BK.JPG)

is there any way to do this in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

Use hold on keyword between different plots.
For example:

```
   plot(x,'r');

   hold on;

   plot(y,'b');
```

It will plot both `x` and `y` in red and blue colors on same graph.

Comment: x and y should have different values, otherwise x will replace y

Comment: so here is what I ended up doing because what you told me wasn't getting both of the distributions to be equal size and fit evenly on the same axes:           >> x = [-2.5:.1:2.5];
>> norm = normpdf(x,0,1)                                                                                  >> y = [-2.5:.1:2.5];
>> horm = normpdf(y,-1.5,1);                                                                         >> plot(x,norm)
>> hold on

Comment: next I manually edited the x axis to go from -4 to 4;  then: >> plot(y,horm);             now my problem is as follows: for some reason, the distribution called "horm" gets plotted, but the leftmost quarter of the distribution is totally missing ...... any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I guess this is just in plotting. Try manually extending the x-axis to left from axis properties of matlab fig plot

Comment: Can you tell why have you added -1.5,1 in normpdf of y.

Comment: because I want the two distributions to cross at about the -.75 mark on the x axis, and setting the mean of "horm" to -1.5 with a standard deviation of 1 accomplishes this

Comment: attach a snapshot of the plot you are getting and also the values that you are plotting on x and y for both curves

Comment: everything about the x and y values is listed in my code above (x has a mean of 0 and standard deviation of 1 and y has a mean of -1.5 and a standard deviation of 1...and both distributions are both 5 units in length).....here's a link to the image:     http://imgur.com/a/Spn1D